# How can I fix my code so that I can keep on adding the sum of the indices instead of it just returning one index?

Tags: python, indexing

I am new to python and taking an intro class, one of my homework asks to write a function that takes, as arguments, a string and a character. If the character is in the string, return the sum of the indices that the character occurs. Otherwise, return False. We can not use the find() or index() built-in functions.

This is my code so far

```
def addIndices(myString, myChar):
    summy= 0
    for i in myChar:
        if i not in myString:
            return False 
    else:
        for i in myString:
            if i in myString:
                summy += 1
    return summy
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: You have `for i in myString`. If `i` is a character from `myString`, what do you think `if i in myString` will do? What is the condition that you _actually_ want to check before incrementing `summy`?

Comment: `return sum(i for i, char in enumerate(myString) if char == myChar) if myChar in myString else False` should do it.

Comment: `myChar` is supposed to be a single character. Why do you need to loop over it to check if it exists in `myString`? (Not that it will do any harm, since there will be only one iteration anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code. Note you said to return the sum of indices, so you need to add the index (starting at 0) of each matching character, not just to add 1 for each matching character.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def addIndices(myString, myChar):
    summy = 0
    if not myChar in myString:
         return False
    else:
        i = 0
        for ch in myString:
            if myChar == ch:
                summy += i
            i += 1
    return summy

sum = addIndices('it is a test', 'i')

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like what follows:

```py
def addIndices(myString, myChar):
  sum = 0
  for i, ch in enumerate(myString):
    if ch == myChar:
      sum += i
  if sum == 0: return False
  return sum
addIndices("hiii", "o")
```

If your homework indicates that indicies are starting from 0, change `sum += i` line with `sum +=i+1`

Comment: @mkrieger1 After your comment, I searched about homework questions in SO and it seems you are right! I misunderstood and edited the answer as per your comment. Thank you.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you, my apologies I could not form it into a question but I was having trouble on how to add the indices together if the character was there, I kept getting just 1.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani Thank you! I was able to solve my issue with my coding.